# How can I use electron js app as a web browser for one localhost link?

Tags: javascript, php, electron

I have developed Angular app with PHP back-end. To run angular front end, it must access data from the back end too. I need to run front end as a electron desktop app.

I tried it with Electorn by using  `mainWindow.loadFile('index.html')` and configuring file paths of index file. 
i set paths as this

`<script src="C:/xampp/htdocs/foo-html/assets/js/app.min.js"></script>`

and like this

`<script src="assets/js/app.min.js"></script>`

but it won't work without the server. So I need to run the 127.0.0.0:8000/index.html link inside electronJS app. Is this possible and if it is, How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

It's really as easy as using [`BrowserWindow#loadURL ()`](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window) to load a webpage from any protocol, rather than using `BrowserWindow#loadFile ()` which will load a webpage from your filesystem, just like this:

```
mainWindow.loadURL ("http://localhost:8000/index.html");
```